# Set a user's primary group in AD with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm working on an off-boarding playbook, but having trouble with group management.

Be default, all users are in `Domain Users` obviously, but when we terminate them, we add them to a group called `TerminatedUsers` and set it as the primary group. We also remove the the user's group memberships.

Currently I'm stuck with the fact that I can remove the primary group of a user, so I have to change it to a different primary group (aka `TerminatedUsers`). I don't want to use Powershell for this (or do I?).

Here's the task that should handle this:

```yaml
- name: Remove user from all group except TerminatedUsers
  community.windows.win_domain_user:
    name: "{{ username }}"
    groups:
      - TerminatedUsers
    groups_action: replace
  delegate_to: "{{ jump_host }}"
```

The outcome of this is that the user is a member of both `Domain Users` and `TerminatedUsers`.
What is an elegant, yet idempotent way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve all groups where the user is part of:

```yaml
- name: get all groups of user
  ansible.windows.win_shell: |
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity "{{ username }}" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
  register: all_groups
  delegate_to: "{{ jump_host }}"
  changed_when: false
```

Then add the user to your group, and remove the user from all other groups:

```yaml
- name: set TerminatedUsers as primary group
  community.windows.win_domain_group_membership:
    name: TerminatedUsers
    members:
      - "{{ username }}"
    state: present
  delegate_to: "{{ jump_host }}"

- name: remove user from all groups but not TerminatedUsers
  community.windows.win_domain_group_membership:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    members:
      - "{{ username }}"
    state: absent
  delegate_to: "{{ jump_host }}"
  loop: "{{ all_groups.stdout_lines }}"
  when: "'TerminatedUsers' not in item"
```